# How to get lat & long from POSTCODE and country restriction alone

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, geocoding

Is it possible to correctly return the lat lon just from the postcode & country restriction?

Here's what I have:

```
$scope.getLatLongFromPostcode = function(code) {        
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    address: code + '', // force string hack
    componentRestrictions : {
      country : 'AU'
    }
  }, function postcodesearch(results, status) {
    var searchCode = null;            
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var location = [results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()]
      console.log('location', location[0],location[1]
    }
  });
}
```

While this seems to work for some post codes, not all work, example:

2263 returns -33.2504355, 151.5077645 which is correctly pointing to the right suburb.

However If I search 6937 it returns -25.274398 133.77513599999997 which is dead center of Australia which is incorrect as it should be somewhere near Perth in Tuart Hill.

Comment: As well as specifying the country and postcode, could you also supply the  `locality` to do component filtering?  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ComponentFiltering I'm guessing a four digit code isn't enough to uniquely identify an address in a country as big as Australia.

Comment: I've tried using that exact resource however 6937 still returns no results.

Comment: what did you specify for the locality?

Comment: I only have post code, as my question states I can only search by postcode, so I used 'postalCode' : code in my component restrictions but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It seems that google's geocoder database is missing 6937 and is returning the geocoded results for Australia.

Comment: Australian postal service returns no results for this postal code either. http://auspost.com.au/postcode/6937. Also, public Google Maps has the postal code for said street as 6060. Here's the query: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Tuart+Hill+WA+6060,+Australia/@-31.8973663,115.8318981,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x2a32affe5d3d9ea7:0x504f0b535df52d0.

Comment: Geocode query for the coordinates from public Google Maps shows accurate results.